# TinyMCE 4.x count character

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I trying to create character count on tiny mce 4.x. I create counter but I can limit user to type.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea',    

   charLimit : 20, // this is a default value which can get modified later
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('KeyUp', function(e) {

            var tinymax, tinylen, htmlcount;

            tinymax = this.settings.charLimit;

            tinylen = this.getContent().length;

            $("#charNum").html(tinylen);

            if (tinylen > tinymax) {
               $("#charNum").html(tinylen);     
               // STOP TYPE     
            }

        });
    } 
});
```

I add e.preventDefault(); but now user can not delete input

```
 if (tinylen > tinymax) {
    $("#charNum").html(tinylen);        
    e.preventDefault();    
 }
```

Comment: I add e.preventDefault(); but now user can not delete input

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
var max = 5;

$('#a').on('keyup', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if( val.length > max ){
        $(this).val(val.substr(val, max));
    }
});
```

So, if the input length is higher than maximum permitted, just cut it.

[Check the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/e4bcg6ky/)